# Cannot change data.frame to factor in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, factors

I cannot figure out why my for loop does not change the `data.frame` into a data set with `factors`. This is what I wrote:

```
# Turning data set into dataframe -------------------------------------------------------
NB_mcar <- data.frame(subset_MCAR)

# Giving variables original names and making variables readable -------------------------
names(NB_mcar) <- gsub(" ", "_", names(ipums), fixed=TRUE)

# Converting to factors for categorical prediction --------------------------------------
for (i in 1:ncol(NB_mcar)) {
    NB_mcar[, i] <- as.factor(NB_mcar[, i])
}
```

If I check if the data set was transformed with `is.factor(NB_mcar)` I get the outcome `[1]FALSE`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying tho check whether the whole dataframe was converted to a factor. See `str(NB_mcar)` to check whether all columns are factors. A dataframe cannot be a factor, only a column of a dataframe.

Comment: `sapply(NB_mcar, is.factor)` would also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code must work just fine. To check the structure of the data.frame use:

```
str(NB_mcar)
```

FYI: A data frame cannot be a factor. Only its column can be converted into factors.